# how would i display a directory from another server

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to merge content from 2 servers. The main domain is domain.com.

I want a subfolder url:

http://domain.com/subfolder/

But I want the main server to get the content from another server. So the file.htm would be stored in the secondary server but would appear as:

http://domain.com/subfolder/file.htm

on the main server.

The main server uses Node.

Ive tried a subdomain but it has seo issues.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: You might want to look into `HAProxy` for doing the job